# How do i get the removing predicate editor row after clicking on the "-" Button in NSPredicateEditor?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nspredicateeditor, nspredicateeditorrow

I have an NSPredicatedEditor with Custom Row Templates. I would like to know the removing custom row template after clicking on "-" in NSPredicateEditor. I have tried over-riding the below method which actually provides index as a parameter but it doesn't return the exact index when its included with sub row(Nested Compound Row Templates). I'm looking for the instance of the removing row template while its been removed.

> removeRowsAtIndexes:includeSubrows:

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? The templates are used to create criteria, there isn't a template for each row.

Comment: As i said i have custom row templates with custom views added in the one

Comment: You can't get the template.

Comment: In a little test app I see that each row has its own custom template. I don't think you can get the template. You might get the views with `displayValuesForRow:`.